# Sum of values with same month

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'dates': ['2010-01-29', '2011-06-14', '2012-01-18'], 'values': [4, 3, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('dates')
df.index = df.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Having a dataframe where the index is a date, how would I go about adding a new column caled 'Month' that is the sum of all values for that month but doesn't "enter the future" as in saying that it only adds up days before its date.

This is what the column would look like.

```
'Month': [4, 3, 12]
```

Comment: Those are the values corresponding to its day, 4 is for '2010-01-29' and 8 for '2012-01-18'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` is your friend here

```
def sum_from_months_prior(row, df):
    '''returns sum of values in row month, 
    from all dates in df prior to row date'''

    month = pd.to_datetime(row).month

    all_dates_prior = df[df.index <= row]
    same_month = all_dates_prior[all_dates_prior.index.month == month]

    return same_month["values"].sum()

data = {'dates': ['2010-01-29', '2011-06-14', '2012-01-18'], 'values': [4, 3, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('dates', inplace = True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df["dates"] = df.index
df.sort_index(inplace = True)

df["Month"] = df["dates"].apply(lambda row: sum_from_months_prior (row, df))
df.drop("dates", axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

***desired df:***

```
            values  Month
dates
2010-01-29       4      4
2011-06-14       3      3
2012-01-18       8     12
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use pandas `TimeGrouper`

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).sum()
```

Comment: Forgot about `TimeGrouper`, this is the way to do it.

Comment: `pd.TimeGrouper()` was formally deprecated in pandas `v0.21.0` in favor of `pd.Grouper()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45156301/7116413).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this.  The first would be to resample to monthly using `df.resample(...).sum()`.

You could also create a month column from the index, using `df['month'] = df.index.month`, then perform a groupby operation, `df.groupby('month').sum()` - which method is best depends on what you want to do with the data.