# pandas: where is the documentation for TimeGrouper?

Tags: python, pandas

I use `Pandas` a lot and its great. I use `TimeGrouper` as well, and its great. I actually dont know where is the documentation about `TimeGrouper`. Is there any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`pd.TimeGrouper()` was [formally deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0210-deprecations) in pandas v0.21.0 in favor of [`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html).

The best use of `pd.Grouper()` is within `groupby()` when you're also grouping on non-datetime-columns.  If you just need to group on a frequency, use `resample()`.

For example, say you have:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(444)

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.choice(['x', 'y'], size=50),
                       'b': np.random.rand(50)},
                      index=pd.date_range('2010', periods=50))
>>> df.head()
            a         b
2010-01-01  y  0.959568
2010-01-02  x  0.784837
2010-01-03  y  0.745148
2010-01-04  x  0.965686
2010-01-05  y  0.654552
```

You *could* do:

```
>>> # `a` is dropped because it is non-numeric
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()
                  b
2010-01-31  18.5123
2010-02-28   7.7670
```

But the above is a little unnecessary because you're only grouping on the index.  Instead you could do:

```
>>> df.resample('M').sum()
                    b
2010-01-31  16.168086
2010-02-28   9.433712
```

to produce the same result.

Conversely, here's a case where `Grouper()` would be useful:

```
>>> df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'a']).sum()
                   b
           a        
2010-01-31 x  8.9452
           y  9.5671
2010-02-28 x  4.2522
           y  3.5148
```

For some more detail, take a look at Chapter 7 of Ted Petrou's [*Pandas Cookbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1784393878).

Comment: can I still do stuff like `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'brad']).mean()` ?

Answer (score 3):

`pandas.TimeGrouper()` [was deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/08a66e111a60b9a25fb59a0dcc691c3f1ec0ad1e/doc/source/whatsnew/v0.21.0.txt#L940) in favour of [`pandas.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) in pandas v0.21.

Use `pandas.Grouper()` instead.